# Writing S3 bucket csv to redshift using kinesis

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I have 3 types of csv in my s3 bucket and want to flow them into respective redshift tables based on csv prefix . I am thinking to use Kinesis to stream data to redshift as file in s3 will be dropped every 5 min. I am all new to aws and  not sure how to achieve this.

I have gone through aws documentation but not sure how to achieve this

Comment: Kinesis is typically used for streaming data but it sounds like you're already collecting your data into s3. There's better options for moving your s3 data into redshift, one of them is simply using the COPY command, another would be AWS Glue https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/tutorial-loading-data.html

Comment: There are 3 types of csv getting oushed to S3 bucket at every 5 mins each and evry day  and i want to push it to Redshift to three different tables as a continous process. Does AWs glue allow to do that. Can i single job let me schedule time to run data load from 3 csv to 3 redshift tables

Comment: schedule a command to run a redshift copy on a regular basis - easier faster cheaper

Comment: I understand but if i have 3 csv written in same bucket every 5 min,does it make sense to copy to respective Redshift tables directly or stream through kinesis and set Redshift tabels as destination